# Reasons for using leading or trailing boolean operators in multiline if statement

Tags: javascript, eslint

For if conditions with multiple boolean operators, I've seen newlines used for readability.  I remember seeing someone's eslint rule about whether the boolean operators joining the parts of the condition should be leading or trailing.  I don't remember where I saw it, what the rule was they used, or what their reasoning was.

Trailing:

```
if (
  someVariable &&
  otherThing
) {
  // code
}
```

Leading:

```
if (
  someVariable
  && otherThing
) {
  // code
}
```

What are the reasons for preferring one flavor? Which one lends itself to cleaner git diffs?

Comment: Sorry about the original title. "Which is better" _is_ asking for an opinion, for sure.  What I'm after are the reasons why someone might choose either approach.  I definitely don't want to know what individuals' opinions are on which one is better.  I just want to know the technical differences.

Comment: "*I just want to know the technical differences*" JavaScript doesn't care, either way. Leading operators should have slightly clearer Git diffs because adding or removing an operator and variable/expression will only affect one line, while trailing operators means you'd have to add or remove from the previous line too.

Comment: But wait, you can have best of both worlds by using a trailing boolean literal. E.g. "bool1 &&\n bool2 &&\n True".

Answer (score 0):

The diff thing is less important than indentation. Trailing keeps indentation intact in more complex scenarios. Here is an example. Notice that the indentation in the first example has all of the related items at the same indentation levels whereas in the second your eye has to go to the right because the &&s are at the start of the line. The impact is even greater if you are scanning from the bottom up.

```
if (
   someVariable &&
   isComplexButEvalsToTrueOrFalse({
     myProp: "myValue"
   }) &&
   isComplexButEvalsToTrueOrFalse({
     myProp: "myOtherValue"
   })
) {
  // code
}
```

vs

```
if (
   someVariable
   && isComplexButEvalsToTrueOrFalse({
     myProp: "myValue"
   })
   && isComplexButEvalsToTrueOrFalse({
     myProp: "myOtherValue"
   })
) {
  // code
}
```

At the end of the day it is all subjective.  For what it is worth Prettier uses the trailing method unless the last item is an empty array or object and it can fit it all on one line. It only indents if there is a nested expression and in that case uses [parenthesis and indentation](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/567#issuecomment-278676484) to make it clear. Generally speaking you indent when going to another level and while the &&s themselves are not nested, the eye certainly has to dart inwards to read the name of the var/fn/obj/arr so it has a similar effect.

Comment: I agree that whether diffs or indentation are more or less important than each other is subjective.  I hadn't thought about leading operators making it so that each part of the conditional don't line up, which is definitely an objective technical point to consider as people form their opinions.  Thanks for bringing up the very valid point.